# Default language in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, locale

I have Windows 7, and I set up English like default language, but every time I open new  window keyboard layout become be non English, but second language, and it occurs only when I login with local admin, when I login with domain user, all work fine...

Any idea what this voodoo is?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1):

What did you set the defaults to? You can go to *Region and Language* → *Keyboards and Languages* → *Change keyboards*. This will take you to the *Text Services and Input Languages* dialog where you can set a default language and keyboard layout.

Keep in mind that the language and the layout are independent of each other. I'm using German as input language with US International as keyboard layout for example. By default Windows installs the language's usual keyboard layout as well which can sometimes lead to confusion.

Comment: Thank you for response. I set English (US) to default, this is not work...